# How to allow Disallowed Key Characters. in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting error with url in codeigniter.

url string is

coa=1015%20·%20SALARY%20WAGES%20&%20BONUS

which is actually

coa=1015 · SALARY WAGES & BONUS. I think & is creating the problem.

I had tried some solutions whihare already accepted answers in stack overflow.But they are for other characters.

I have tried following things like in config file

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

change this code to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_=+-'
```

Also change function in input.php of system core file as someone has suggested this in stackoverflow.

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    return $str;
}
```

But still i am facing the issue.

So can you please suggest me how can i solve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Leave blank to allow all characters as following

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

But It has security issue.